# codeigniter: inserting value from array 1 to array 2?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

i have an array like this

array 1

```
array(3) { 
   [0]=> string(2) "47" 
   [1]=> string(2) "48" 
   [2]=> string(2) "49" 
}
```

i have plan to giving array with name, the array name is **number**

array 2

```
array(3) { 
[0]=> object(stdClass)#18 (2) { 
      ["address"]=> string(9) "Address 1" 
      ["price"]=> string(16) "120000" } 
[1]=> object(stdClass)#21 (2) { 
      ["address"]=> string(9) "Address 2"      
      ["price"]=> string(16) "150000" } 
[2]=> object(stdClass)#20 (2) { 
      ["address"]=> string(9) "Address 3" 
      ["price"]=> string(16) "180000" } 
}
```

I want to inserting array 1 into array 2 which same array key

I want to insert array 1 data into array 2 accordance with the key array . so i I was expecting to be joined both of arrays and became joined array like this

```
array(3) { 
[0]=> object(stdClass)#18 (2) { 
      ["address"]=> string(9) "Address 1" 
      ["price"]=> string(16) "120000" 
      ["number"]=> string(2) "47" } 
[1]=> object(stdClass)#21 (2) { 
      ["address"]=> string(9) "Address 2"      
      ["price"]=> string(16) "150000" 
      ["number"]=> string(2) "48"} 
[2]=> object(stdClass)#20 (2) { 
      ["address"]=> string(9) "Address 3" 
      ["price"]=> string(16) "180000" 
      ["number"]=> string(2) "49"} 
}
```

is there any way to create or manipulate into an array like that ? my array is **dynamically** so number of array can be changed anytime.

I would greatly appreciate it if you could help me

Comment: would seem *trivial* to do with a `foreach()` loop. why not give it a go.

Comment: get you explain how looping do you mean ? I do not understand how the implementation of the concept of the array foreach loop @Dagon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read up on the basic language [control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php) and [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) in particular.

```php
foreach ($array2 as $index => $object) {
    if (isset($array1[$index])) {
        $object->number = $array1[$index];
    }
}
```

Outcome:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (3) {
    ["address"]=>
    string(9) "Address 1"
    ["price"]=>
    string(6) "120000"
    ["number"]=>
    string(2) "47"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (3) {
    ["address"]=>
    string(9) "Address 2"
    ["price"]=>
    string(6) "150000"
    ["number"]=>
    string(2) "48"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (3) {
    ["address"]=>
    string(9) "Address 3"
    ["price"]=>
    string(6) "180000"
    ["number"]=>
    string(2) "49"
  }
}
```

Here is a **[Codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ymEOk3)** demo